# Php Facebook Api Delete Call

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have developed a facebook application that shares posts to pages as they were posted by the admin of that page. Is there any way that I can delete these posts ?

I am aware of the call :

```
$facebook->api("/{post_id}","DELETE");
```

where `post_id` is the id returned with this call:

```
$posted =$facebook->api('/'page id'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

I read in facebook documentation that a post can be deleted only by the application that made it. So since my app published posts as they were posted by the page admin means that they were not made by the application?

Each time I try to make that call it throws me an error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /fb/base_facebook.php on line 1340

As for the authorization I have all permissions that are required to post to someone else page, manage pages, offline access, publish stream etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `access_token` of the same user you has published the app.

In your case the admin(you) is posting, so get the access_token of his and make the `\DELETE` call- this will delete the post.

Comment: um yes ok in this method where does the app access token goes ? after the delete method ? $facebook->api("/{post_id}","DELETE",$accessToken);

Comment: `/post-id?access_token=APP-ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: You can test your calls here also: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: any idea how to syntax the delete in open graph ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Open Graph isn't any tool from which you can delete something?

Comment: $del = $facebook->api("/00000_000000?access_token=$AccessToken","DELETE");      I am using the call and i get an error                                                     Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /var/www/external.dk/www/facebook/fb/base_facebook.php on line 1340

Comment: You used the app access token?

Comment: Make sure you are using the app access token of the same app that is creating the posts.

Comment: yes i am using the app access token that i found it https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/  something like 00000000|sdfsdfsdfsdfsd so the $AccessToken variable is filled with the app access token . But i get that error                         here are the permision i use :public_profile, basic_info, read_stream, publish_checkins, status_update, photo_upload, video_upload, email, create_note, share_item, export_stream, publish_stream, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_friends and offline access i don't know why is not shown here

Comment: You are not understanding the things here. What I'm saying is that ge the app token of the same app that published the post, of course you are not doing that and getting the error again and again. Permissions here are not of relevance at all!

Comment: The app token of the same that published the post ist something like 00000000|sdfsdfsdfsdfsd ? in the access token tool indicates the App access token  what do you mean ? what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Strange. Get the access token of admin and then delete it. This will surely delete the post. For testing, go here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and select your app from the drop down on upper right of the page, and get the access token

Comment: still nothin i use the     $del = $facebook->api("/objectid?access_token=token","DELETE"); and in the access token i use the access token of the app or the access token i use to make the post in the page and i get the error OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action. And test this in a page of mine where i am the admin ...

Comment: In graph explorer the GET work fine when i use the object id i get a list of all the info of the object when i use delete i get : "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /437292326416179", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1                                                          But i notice that in open graph the object is from the page not from the app does it has to do with that maybe ?